# UICollectionView Cell position changing in IPhone6

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm really stuck on this as I have a CollectionView and it contains 2 rows.The width of One row is equal to width of viewController(320).It is working fine in iphone 4 and Iphone 5s but in Iphone 6 it is looking like this..

[image]

The blue one is row one and Red is row two...
I had configure the collectionview like this...

```
 [flowLayout setItemSize:self.bounds.size];

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

so it is self.bounds on every view and it working fine but in Iphone 6s it not fiiting self.bounds why..plz help

Comment: I would suggest that you add your UICollectionView from a storyboard/xib a link the outlet to your ViewController. That way you can set the constraints of the UICollectionView in your storyboard/xib and avoid that initialization of the UICollectionView altogether

Comment: Thnxx For attention,Actually I had made a custom class of UICollectionview and i'm using it where ever i need it.

Comment: In the storyboard/xib you can specify in the inspector that the UICollectionView be of your own custom class that you have, you can even specify your custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout if you implemented one. Cheers

Comment: Thnxx but Can't i resolve this issue without xib...

Comment: I guess you can try setting your frame in the method `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (don't forget to call super), I've seen cases where the bounds of the view aren't correct until it goes through viewWillAppear. I still think that the proper way to go is with storyboards and constraints though.

Comment: I'm using storyboard and i'm putting a UIView in it and applying constraints too..and then changing the class of uiview too uicollectionview class

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to do `self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];` you are actually replacing your already loaded collectionView for another collectionView without your constraints. if you want to set the layout you can do `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;`

Comment: Thnxx...For help but no luckk...by using your method it is not showing me anything.

Comment: Thnxx for help this problem is solved by layoutsubviews...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `self.bound` you can try out this

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Comment: I had tried this but when my cell size will be small it will still scroll in full view...